# Is it possible to upload videos with filepond?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I am trying to use filepond in a Modal to upload image and video.
The image uploading is working, but the video is not. So, I am not sure if filepond works with videos.

```
<div className='uploadMedia'>
              <div className='uploadImg'>
                <FilePond
                  files={image}
                  onupdatefiles={setImage}
                  allowMultiple={false}
                  maxFiles={1}
                 
                  name="imagePost" 
                  labelIdle= "Elige o arrastra tus imágenes"
                  className='imageInput'
                />
              </div>
              <div className='uploadVideo'>
                <FilePond
                  files={video}
                  onupdatefiles={setVideo}
                  allowMultiple={false}
                  maxFiles={1}
                  name="videoPost" 
                  labelIdle= "Elige o arrastra tu video"
                  className='videoInput'
                />
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to know if I can upload videos using filepond. And if it is possible, where is my error? Why cant I upload?